# Serving geospatial files from a file system using GeoWebCache

Tags: references, geowebcache

Is there a primer somewhere for how to go from having various geospatial files (such as shp, dbf, gdp, geotoff, geojpg, geopng) to being able to serve them to a map via service calls to GeoWebCache directly from a file system without having to put something like GeoServer in the loop?

Assuming this is even possible, and I believe it is, but it's not easy to figure out how to do this from the documentation.

Can someone confirm whether or not this is possible, and if so list the steps that would be needed?

Comment: That's not how geowebcache works I'm afraid. You need to add the data to geoserver and then serve the layers through gwc

Comment: Then what is the use of standalone GeoWebCache, as described here? The documentation isn't very thorough. Mostly everything is about GeoServer integration. http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.8.1/introduction/whichgwc.html

Comment: You can point the standalone gwc at a geoserver on another machine

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Odd, because I thought GeoServer was just one possible data store option. Anyone else have insight to offer?

Comment: You can point it at any WMS

Comment: The process of turning spatial data into a rendered map image can be computationally expensive.  GeoWebCache sits in front of a WMS that's rendering maps and caches the images as tiles that can be served up far faster than they could be rendered from scratch.  So GWC can do this for any WMS, not just that provided by GeoServer, but it just does the caching.  If we added the ability to load spatial data and render it, we would be turning it into another GeoServer which would be redundant.